# Finding greater number using awk

Tags: awk

I'm having trouble figuring out if the current line number is greater then the next row then it should print something like for example " the number 53 is greater than 23 " and then compares the next two lines "the number 54 is less than 76". I thinking something along the lines NR%2, but not sure what to do after that. Any hints or suggestions on how this would be done would be greatly appreciated thanks.

An example of this file is:

```
53
23
54
76
12
42
```

Expected outcome

```
the number 53 is greater than 23
the number 54 is less than 76
the number 12 is less than 42
```

Comment: Why change the input file after you get two answers but not improve the explanation or add the expected output?

Comment: sorry i accidentally pushed post without finishing the last bit

Comment: The extra lines in the files did not add anything to the question they just broke the existing answers. With questions like this you should post you input file **along with** the expected output.

Comment: Right.A bit new to this... I'll add the outcome now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this would be what you want:

```
 awk '!(NR%2){print p>=$0?p">="$0:p"<"$0;next}{p=$0}' file
```

output:

```
53>=23
54<76
12<42
```

output with your **new** input file:

```
53>=23
54<76
12<42
43>=4
1<63
34<56
```

you can adjust the text ("greater/less than"). also handle the `==` case if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun here is one way of doing it with coreutils, bc and sed:

```
<infile paste -d' ' - - <( <infile paste -d'<' - - | bc ) | 
sed 's/1$/less/; s/0$/greater/; s/([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) (.*)/the number \1 is \3 than \2/'
```

Output:

```
the number 53 is greater than 23
the number 54 is less than 76
the number 12 is less than 42
```

*Explanation*

The inner paste pipes `n1<n2` to bc with returns a binary vector. The outer paste columnates this vector with pairs of numbers from the input. sed reorganizes its input based on the binary vector.

So if you were only interested in knowing if pairs of lines are greater or less than each other this bit would be enough:

```
<infile paste -d'<' - - | bc
```

Output:

```
0
1
1
```